# In which cases using "provide" and "useClass" can be useful?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

According to [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#aliased-class-providers), you can inject a different object when a provider is a required. When I looked for good reasons to do this, the only information that I found has been the following:

> Suppose an old component depends upon an OldLogger class [...] but for some reason you can't update the old component to use it.

I'm still doubtful. Why, in some cases, I couldn't update the old component? It's not dangerous if a *Component* or a *Directive* expects a class and we inject another one? What are the cases where using `provide` and `useClass` is essential?

Comment: `useClass` is the default and most used strategy and is used if you define your providers like this `providers: [MyClass]` -> `providers: [provide: MyClass, useClass: MyClass]`

Answer (score 6):

In my case I use it when I need to implement different logic other than a default class provided by the angular. For example ErrorHandler is a default class for handling errors in Angular 2+ but I like to use my custom classes for handling errors So I use

```
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }
```

It will tell the angular to use MyErrorHandler class instead of ErrorHandler

Answer (score 5):

`useClass` is for providing alternative implementations

```
{ provide: MyClass, useClass: MyMockClass }
```

which means that when `MyClass` is the type of the constructor parameter where an instance should be injected, a `MyMockClass` instance is injected instead.

`useValue` is to make Angular use a custom instance creation logic

```
providers: [
  DebA, 
  DebB,
  { provide: MyClass, useValue: (a, b) => new MyClass(a, b), deps: [DepA, DebB] }
]
```

or

```
{ provide: 'myServerPort', useValue: 8080 }
```

where Angular wouldn't have a way to provide a value for `'myServerPort'` if not `useValue` would be available.

Answer (score 0):

*useClass* can be used to (kind of) fulfil *dependency inversion* design principle (aka DIP). But as far as I understand, DIP is not fulfilled since a module depends on a concrete implementation specified under *useClass*